# Mysql timestamps and php date()

Tags: php, mysql

The mysql timestamp is in a standard format 2013-02-20 02:25:21, when I use date('H:i:s',$date) I get the same invalid output 18:33:33, how can I get the right output? hour:minute:seconds

Comment: timestamp in PHP is an integer representing the number of s from 01/01/1970. `2013-02-20 02:25:21` is not a timestamp, it is a date format named TIMESTAMP in MySql. SO you have to first transform the entry into a valid date/timestamp before trying to print it in different format. Take a look at `strtotime` : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Tip : try with MYSQL [`DATE_FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2013-02-20 02:25:21', '%H:%i:%s');
```

if you want to do it only with PHP then use [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

```
 date('H:i:s',strtotime('2013-02-20 02:25:21'));
```

Comment: More information on PHP [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) with all the formatting options. I used this to format a MySQL timestamp to something more friendly. `$c['ICommentCreatedF'] = date('M D, Y h:i A',strtotime($c['ICommentCreated'] ));`

Answer (score 21):

use this `date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($date));`

Answer (score 1):

This might help you

```
date('H:i:s',strtotime($date));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this  `date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($date));`

Answer (score 0):

Try [`strptime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php)

```
strptime($date,"%H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: @RonaldoMySQLDBA...I change the link to PHP manual...hope it make more sense.:)